# notepad++: regex for groups with whitespace

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I m trying to extract 1st to 7th groups from lines in np++ replace tool. 6th and 7th groups may contain whitespaces. Problem is that groups are delimited by variable lenght whitespaces.
Example line where 6th and 7th groups contain whitespaces:

```
SEP111112222555 \+49888880000222  NULL      NULL             t              LG-COBA-DEBER01 HG_BER01 493222225555                                   LG-COBA-DEBER01 HG_BER01 493222225555
```

Find what:

```
(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\S+) +(\A\S+.+\S\z) +(\A\S.+\S\z)
```

Replace with:

```
\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7
```

It finds no match. Also tried with \' and ` string boundary chars.

Expected output:

```
SEP111112222555,\+49888880000222,NULL,NULL,t,LG-COBA-DEBER01 HG_BER01 493222225555,LG-COBA-DEBER01 HG_BER01 493222225555
```

Comment: Drop the `\A`'s and `\z`'s.

Comment: in that case the 6th groups takes the rest and group 7 will have only the last string which is 493222225555.

Comment: And what's the expected output then? You haven't specified in your question

Comment: `\A` doesn't have a normal behavior in N++ and it shouldn't be there.

Comment: sorry, i missed it. now expected output specified

Comment: How many spaces between word characters are allowed within a group like 6?

Comment: only 1. but unfortunately admins may accidentaly type 2. but in this example we can say 1.

Comment: If it's only sixth and 7th groups, you can work around it but if it could be all groups that may have spaces between then no way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
(.+?) +([^ ].*?) +([^ ].*?) +([^ ].*?) +([^ ].*?) {2,}([^ ].*?) {2,}([^ ].*)
```

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/vlcwcK/3/

Comment: {2,} - means that delimeter is more than 1 whitespace. I use it for groups 6th and 7th

Comment: would you like to update your response with this link? https://regex101.com/r/vlcwcK/3/
(added the output of the substitution also)

Comment: thanks. this captures the  groups as expected. i tested with regex testers. however when i try to use it in np++, it says "replaced 1" and nothing happens OR doesnt say anything and nothing happens.